# Writing to a custom position in a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file formatted like below:

```
Name,Location,Note

Jerry,Berlin,TestNote
```

Now I want to grab the text from a JTextPane and write it to the Note position for a specific Name.

I am getting the selected name with:

```
String check = String.valueOf(liste.getSelectedItem());
```

Can anyone help me how to write the text from the JTextPane as a note to the selected name

Thanks

Comment: String check gets the selected Item from a drop down list with the Names

Comment: The project is a java project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library has nice API to read\write from CSV files, try it for your purpose http://opencsv.sourceforge.net